# itemSelectionChanged() signal of QListWidget when clear() was called

Tags: qt, signals, qlistwidget

Sorry for the bulky title.

I have a class containing a `QListWidget`.
I connected it's `itemSelectionChanged()` signal to a custom slot.

When I call `QListWidget::clear()`, the slot gets called (as expected) but a call to `QListWidget::count()` in this slot returns the number of items the `QListWidget` had before.

A call to `count()` right after the call to `clear()` (when the signal was processed as described) returns the correct number `0`.

I prepared [a complete demo project](http://astro.uni-tuebingen.de/~wende/ListWidgetTest.zip). Most important is this source file:

```
#include "ListWidgetTest.hpp"
#include "ui_ListWidgetTest.h"
#include <QDebug>

ListWidgetTest::ListWidgetTest(QWidget* parent)
    : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::ListWidgetTest)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        QListWidgetItem* item = new QListWidgetItem(QString("Item %1").arg(i));
        ui->listWidget->addItem(item);
    }

    QObject::connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     this, SLOT(clearList()));

    QObject::connect(ui->listWidget, SIGNAL(itemSelectionChanged()),
                     this, SLOT(selectionChanged()));
}

ListWidgetTest::~ListWidgetTest()
{
    delete ui;
}

void ListWidgetTest::clearList()
{
    qDebug() << "void ListWidgetTest::clearList()";
    ui->listWidget->clear();
    qDebug() << "clearList: ui->listWidget->count() is " << ui->listWidget->count();
}

void ListWidgetTest::selectionChanged()
{
    qDebug() << "void ListWidgetTest::selectionChanged()";
    qDebug() << "selectionChanged: ui->listWidget->count() is " << ui->listWidget->count();
}
```

**Output**

```
void ListWidgetTest::clearList() 
void ListWidgetTest::selectionChanged() 
selectionChanged: ui->listWidget->count() is  5
clearList: ui->listWidget->count() is  0
```

**What happens**

1. The list gets populated.
2. Every click on an item calls `selectionChanged()`
3. A click on the button calls `clearList()`
4. The call to `QListWidget::clear()` *also emits the signal* and the slot gets called
5. The number of items **has not changed yet**

Answer (score 1):

You can add "Qt::QueuedConnection" to both of QObject::connection. Like:

```
connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                 this, SLOT(clearList()), Qt::QueuedConnection);

connect(ui->listWidget, SIGNAL(itemSelectionChanged()),
                 this, SLOT(selectionChanged()), Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

It is works. But sorry I don't know why. Maybe queued connection method can solve multi-signal order problem.

Comment: Some explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051553/qt-signals-queuedconnection-and-directconnection)

Answer (score 0):

First of all `QListWidget::clear()` is a SLOT and not a `SIGNAL`. So obviously it is not emitting/triggering the signal `itemSelectionChanged()`.

You might be accidentally triggering this `itemSelectionChanged()` just before calling `clear()`. Check whether you are triggering `itemchanged()` or `selectionchanged()` or any other events that trigger `itemSelectionChanged()` before calling `clear()`.

```
 One possible solution is to declare a custom signal and emit this signal just 
 after calling clear(). And connect it to the custom slot you have defined.You
 will get the expected value in your SLOT
```

Comment: The SIGNAL itemSelectionChanged() IS emitted by calling the SLOT clear(). Since clear removes all items, the selection changes and thus the signal is emitted. Your solution is nevertheless possible but does not explain the problem.

Comment: What I did is on a button click I called clear. And in the SLOT(corresponding to itemselectionchanged()) I put the code to display the count in a lineedit.But nothing got displayed. So what should I infer from this, eh? Please put some of your code here.

Comment: Created a demo project and linked it.

Comment: executed it and output in my system was..... void ListWidgetTest::clearList() 
clearList: ui->listWidget->count() is  0. And no messages from Selectionchanged().

Comment: And when I called Selectionchanged() in clearlist() after clear(), output was..void ListWidgetTest::clearList() 
clearList: ui->listWidget->count() is  0 
void ListWidgetTest::selectionChanged() 
selectionChanged: ui->listWidget->count() is  0

Comment: When I immediately click on clear (button) I get the same result as you. But when I first select an item and then click the button I definitely get the signal emitted... I add output to my post.

Comment: Yeah, now me too got the same.electionChanged: ui->listWidget->count() is  5 
void ListWidgetTest::clearList() 
void ListWidgetTest::selectionChanged() 
selectionChanged: ui->listWidget->count() is  5 
clearList: ui->listWidget->count() is  0

Comment: As I told you, since this clear is a SLOT, it does not restrict any other signals to have emitted in the meantime. Means other signal may get triggered even before completion of clear(). This happens because as some item is selected and when we call clear(). first thing that happens is, the selected row get deselected(thus triggering itemselectionchanged() and still the count value is 5 for the triggered signal as the clear process is yet to finish).Thus it prints 5.